# 1960s/1970s Marvel (?) comic - group of superheroes trapped in a yellow, cubic dimension

Tags: story-identification, comics

This comic was part of a series. I read it in the early-to-mid 2000s, definitely before 2006, but I think that the comic was actually released much earlier in the '60s or the '70s. I remember the comic having several fantastic full-page adverts: learn how to throw your voice, X-ray specs, itchy powder, etc.

It was most likely a Marvel comic. There was a group of heroes who were possibly the X-Men. The group was a mixed bag of superheroes, some could fly, some were human, some were possibly metallic (Colossus?), all wearing their superhero costumes.

The art style of the 1960/70s Uncanny X-Men comics is very similar to what I remember. The comic was (I think) a mix of black-and-white and colour. It definitely had a few pages in full-colour.

The heroes were trapped in another dimension. I remember the dimension being mainly yellow, with a flat plain the heroes could walk around on (there might have been several flat plains), and in the sky there were floating cubes that flying members of the team were able to get to.

I don't remember how they got to this dimension; the comic was definitely part of a longer series with the earlier episodes possibly explaining how they got there. I don't remember much about the plot, mainly the group just walking about the dimension, trying to figure out where they were and how they could get back.

A specific set of panels I recall is an aerial view of one of the plains, with a few floating blocks scattered above the group. The group was walking towards the edge of the plain. I think someone who could fly was trying to reach one of the floating blocks, flying upwards/towards the reader.

Looking at other comics released around the same time I am almost certain that Beast was part of the team in his human form (before he turned blue and hairy), though I can't remember if he had a yellow stripe or a red stripe on the front of his uniform. It struck me as odd that he wasn't wearing shoes...

Comment: If not all the pages were in color, it must be a reprint - possibly non-American. The original Marvel comics were all either full color or pure B&W large format. If a reduced-color reprint, it is possible that the yellow plain wasn't yellow in the original.

Comment: Around 1970, Beast had both a yellow belt and a red stripe on his uniform. https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1a/4c/7f/1a4c7fcfee962024e504657bfc1173e8--the-beast-originals.jpg